# overwrite qmake variable from command line

Tags: qt, qmake

In a Qt project, I have a variable I use in the code.
This is done by using

```
APP_NAME = "QField"
DEFINES += "APP_NAME=\"\\\"$${APP_NAME}\\\"\""
```

How can I modify this from the command line?

I tried to add `APP_NAME=my_name` in additional arguments of qmake build steps without success.

Note: the APP_NAME and DEFINES lines are within a .pri file which is included in the .pro file called by qmake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I modify this from the command line?

Simply by specifying `APP_NAME=my_name` on the qmake's command line.

> I tried to add APP_NAME=my_name in additional arguments of qmake build steps without success.

That's because of the subsequent overwriting the variable inside your .pro/.pri file. You should add the condition to prevent that:

```
#APP_NAME = "QField"
!defined(APP_NAME, var):APP_NAME = "QField"
```